# Forced Installation manually onto different drive than installer selected; lost access to my Window (its not deleted!)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair, boot-partition, windows-11

Hey fellow Ubuntuans(?),

I bought a Clevo barebones laptop (it actully came with an NVME drive and some RAM...this plays into my question). I also bought (2) 2TB NVMEs I planned to upgrade it it with.

1. I booted up my shiny new laptop and to my surprise it was preloaded with Windows 10. That's cool. So I installed a 2TB NVME in the second slot and migrated the OS to the second drive. Which worked perfectly.
2. I swapped out the primary drive with the other 2TB'er and proceeded to boot up my 22.04 install usb and installed 22.04.
3. Upon my first boot I started up gparted to do some resizing. I discovered Ubuntu installed itself on the secondary drive with Windows. This was not my plan. I tried reinstalling a few more times.
4. I am quite annoyed so I choose a fresh install again but go advanced and force the mount point on the primary NVME, which worked perfectly except Window does not appear in Grub anymore.
5. I've been scouring the web and tried numerous solutions to no avail, both slightly old and current. Note!: Windows is not deleted! I can see the boot and data partitions and even access the data partition in the file manger. However all solutions I have found will not make windows appear back in the Grub boot menu. dmesg yielded: ntfs3: Unknown parameter 'windows_names' as the last entry.

If you made it this far thanks for reading and any advice/help you might provide.

Comment: Can't tell for sure, but you may have run Windows with the "Fast boot" option enabled. This leaves the Windows disks in an unrecognizable (to linux) condition. The standard fix (boot Windows, disable "Fast boot", shut down Windows) seem unavailable to you, so all I can suggest is an internet search

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: Hey karel and waltinator, sorry I'm new to the forums though not Ubuntu. Waltinator: I disabled fastboot out of instinct. karel: I was really hoping the "gparted check" would work but there's nothing wrong with the data partition. The boot manager has been lost somehow. And...Boot Repair told me it fixed it, but alas did not change a thing. Thanks for the pointers though.

Comment: If you ran Boot-Repair post link to its summary report in your question above. Boot-Repair will not fix Windows issues, you need your Windows repair/recovery flash drive for that.